# iPhone - TableView editing and still be able to select

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

I am trying to make a table view that should be half editable and half selectable. I can’t get this to work. Do anyone know how to make this possible. I need to be able to reorder one section of the table view and the other section i need to be able to select.

Also I only want the ReorderControl to be shown, without any other editable control to show. When I make it editable it shrinks my table cells to be smaller. Is there anyway to remove this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several properties on `UITableView` that will help you out.

1. `[tableView setAllowsSelectionDuringEditing:YES];`

Also, the UITableViewDelegate protocol has the following method:

`- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Just return `NO` where ever you want the row to not resize.

You can use the delegate method `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` to say which rows you want to be able to delete, and the data source method `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` for the reordering.